# An alternative to self-join

Tags: sql, t-sql, optimization, relational-database

I have a table that has a reference to itself like this:

```
Id   Total   Prev   Session
1  | 10    | NULL | 1
2  | 15    | 1    | 1
3  | 11    | NULL | 2
4  | 29    | 2    | 1
5  | 19    | 3    | 2
6  | 47    | 4    | 1
```

And I need to get the differences for the specific sessions.
Like this for session 1:

```
1. 10 -- None to 10
2. 5  -- 10 to 15
3. 14 -- 15 to 29
4. 18 -- 29 to 47
```

To do this, I use:

```
SELECT  F.Total - P.Total AS Difference
FROM    Foo F LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Foo P ON F.Prev = P.Id
WHERE   Session = @Session
```

Which is extremely slow.
How can I retrieve these differences faster without altering the table?

Comment: Maybe you can add another column for Difference and calculate it on record insertion and update that field.

Comment: I don't know about SQL server, but on Oracle, this would be an ideal case for analytic functions (probably called windowing functions in SQL server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. This is the fastest query possible, although it may become a lot faster if you add an index on `Session`, `Prev` and `Id`.

Comment: An index on `(Session, Id)` would help, an index on `(Session, Prev, Id)` would not.  You don't know the value of `Prev` when you're looking up the previous session.

Comment: GolezTrol and @Andomar, thank you. I'll add an index on `(Session, Id)`.

Comment: Add a separate index on (prev) as well. That one will help with the join.